# How can i disable other stars if i select 1 group among others in angular 15 using ngb-rating?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, bootstrap-5, angular15

This is the design of UI
[image]

Kindly help me on this.

Suppose I selected 1 star, others should not be clickable and from other stars I should be able to select max count, e.g. if 4 stars then 4 should be selectable not less than that?

```
 <div class="form-outline">
                    <ngb-rating
                      [max]="1"
                      (click)="saveReviews()"
                      formControlName="ratingControl"
                      [(rate)]="selected"
                    ></ngb-rating
                    >|
                    <ngb-rating
                      [max]="2"
                      (click)="saveReviews()"
                      formControlName="ratingControl"
                    ></ngb-rating
                    >|
                    <ngb-rating
                      [max]="3"
                      (click)="saveReviews()"
                      formControlName="ratingControl"
                    ></ngb-rating
                    >|
                    <ngb-rating
                      [max]="4"
                      (click)="saveReviews()"
                      formControlName="ratingControl"
                    ></ngb-rating
                    >|
                    <ngb-rating
                      [max]="5"
                      (click)="saveReviews()"
                      formControlName="ratingControl"
                    ></ngb-rating>
                  </div>



     TS: 
custReviews: custReviews = new custReviews();
isReviewed = false;


 model:
    export class custReviews {
      userId: number = 1;
      productId: number = 1;
      content: string = "";
      rating:  = 0;
    }
```